Why pole mass is physical mass?
Schwartz subsection 18.3.1:

It is important to keep in mind that the pole mass is physical and independent of any subtraction scheme used to set the finite parts of the counterterms.

But I am confused about how pole mass can connected with physical mass. Is physical mass means the mass of a particle at rest?

Yes, physical mass means the mass of the particle at rest. That the pole mass is physical mass is a non-trivial property of scattering amplitudes that can be derived from unitarity and completeness. It typically goes under the topic of "polology", which you can look up and learn yourself.

A sketch of the proof for an interacting (hermitean) scalar theory goes as follows: Consider the two-point function $$\langle 0 | {\rm T} \phi(x) \phi(0) |0\rangle=\theta(x^0)\langle0|\phi(x) \phi(0)|0\rangle+\theta(-x^0)\langle0|\phi(0)\phi(x)|0\rangle.   $$ Insert the identity operator written in the form $$\mathbb{I}=|0\rangle \langle 0|+\int \! d\mu(p) \, |p\rangle \langle p|+\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}\int\! d\mu(p_1) \ldots \int\! d\mu(p_n) \; |p_1,\ldots, p_n \, {\rm in}\rangle \langle p_1,\ldots,p_n \, {\rm in}|$$ between the field operators in the products $\phi(x) \phi(0)$ and $\phi(0) \phi(x)$, respectively. The energy-momentum four-vector $p\equiv (p^0, \vec{p})$ fulfills the energy-momentum relation $p^2=(p^0)^2-\vec{p}^2=m_{\rm phys}^2$, where $m_{\rm phys}$ denotes the physical mass of the associated particle.  The integration measure is given by $$d\mu(p)=\frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3 2p^0}, \quad p^0=\sqrt{m_{\rm phys}^2+\vec{p}^2}.$$ Note that instead of in-states one could equally well use out-states for the multi-particle energy-momentum eigenstates. The two-piont function can thus be rewritten as $$\begin{align}\langle 0|{\rm T}\phi(x) \phi(0)|0\rangle &= \theta(x^0) \int \! d\mu(p) \, e^{-ipx}|\langle0|\phi(0)|p\rangle|^2+\theta(-x^0) \int \! d\mu(p) \, e^{ipx}|\langle 0|\phi(0)|p\rangle|^2\\[5pt] &\;\;\;+\text{contributions from intermediate states with } n\ge 2,    \end{align}$$ where $\langle 0 |\phi(0) |0\rangle=0$ was assumed without loss of generality (in theories with $\langle 0 |\phi(0)|0\rangle \ne 0$, $\phi(x)$ can be replaced by $\phi(x)-\langle 0 |\phi(0) |0\rangle$).
The matrix element $\langle 0 |\phi(0)|p\rangle$ is independent of $p$ because of Lorentz invariance. The one-particle energy-momentum eigenstate $$|p\rangle \equiv {\Large|}\sqrt{m_{\rm phys}^2+\vec{p}^2}, \vec{p}{\Large\rangle}$$ can be obtained by a suitably chosen Lorentz boost $U(L)$ acting on the state ${\Large |}m_{\rm phys}, \vec{0}{\Large \rangle}$, i.e. $$|p\rangle =U(L) {\Large |}m_{\rm phys}, \vec{0} {\Large \rangle},$$ where $L {\Large (}m_{\rm phys}, \vec{0}{\Large )}= {\Large (}\sqrt{m_{\rm phys}^2+\vec{p}^2}, \vec{p}{\Large )}$. Using this fact and the relations $U(L)|0\rangle= |0\rangle$ and $U(L)^{-1} \phi(x) U(L) =\phi(L^{-1} x)$ (remember that $\phi$ is supposed to be a scalar field), we find that $$\langle 0 |\phi(0) |p\rangle= \langle 0 |\phi(0) U(L) |m_{\rm phys}, \vec{0}\rangle =\langle 0| U(L)^{-1} \phi(0) U(L) |m_{\rm phys}, \vec{0}\rangle=\langle 0 |\phi(0) |m_{\rm phys} , \vec{0} \rangle  $$ does indeed not depend on $p$. Defining $Z:= |\langle 0 |\phi(0) |p\rangle|^2$, we finally obtain $$\begin{align}\langle 0 |{\rm T}\phi(x) \phi(0) |0\rangle &= Z \left(\theta(x^0) \int \! d\mu(p) \, e^{-ipx}+\theta(-x^0) \int \! d\mu(p) \, e^{ipx}  \right)+\ldots \\[5pt] &= \frac{Z}{i} \int \! \frac{d^d k}{(2\pi)^d} \frac{e^{-ikx}}{m_{\rm phys}^2-k^2+i \epsilon}+\ldots, \end{align}$$ showing that the pole of the two-point function in momentum space determines the physical mass $m_{\rm phys}$. Note also that the position of the pole is not affected by the additional contributions generated by intermediate states with $n\ge 2$ (symbolized by the dots).

For your 2nd Equation, is it supposed to be a sum or product with the ellipses? Not entirely clear

@RC_23 E.g. the term with $n=2$ should be read as $\frac{1}{2} \int d\mu(p_1) d\mu(p_2) |p_1, p_2 , {\rm in} \rangle \langle p_1, p_2 , {\rm in }|$ (i.e. a six-dimensional integration).
